# How to make logs print only on files without being printed out on a console?

Tags: java

Although I've configured handler to write logs to files structure, but I get the log on the console bar when I run the program, how can I masquerade logs so it will only be written on files without exposing to console.

```
static {
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file",
            "log.properties");
    //must initialize loggers after setting above property
}
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.debugz");
public static void main(String[] args) {
try  {
        FileHandler h = new FileHandler("%h/file_%g.log",1,4);
        h.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        logger.addHandler(h);
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Hello");

    }
    catch (Exception error){
        System.out.println("Error : "+error.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try `logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);`

> **[void java.util.logging.Logger.setUseParentHandlers(boolean useParentHandlers)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setUseParentHandlers-boolean-)**
>
> Specify whether or not this logger should send its output to its parent Logger. This means that any LogRecords willalso be written to the parent's Handlers, and potentially to its parent, recursively up the namespace.
>
> Parameters: useParentHandlers true if output is to be sent to the logger's parent.

The above won't work for your use case if a ConsoleHandler has been explicitely added to the logger e.g. `logger.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());` in which case, you may remove that handler if needed via `logger.removeHandler(<handlerToBeRemoved>)`

Hope that helps! Cheers

Comment: but if I remove handler from logger, how can I pass log messages into FileHandler though

Comment: You don't have to remove the FileHandler. That was just an example if you want to explicitely remove another kind of handler (e.g a ConsoleHandler)